# Performance issue with JSON input

Tags: json, mongodb, pentaho, kettle

I am loading mysql table from a mongodb source through kettle.
Mongodb table has more than 4 million records and when I run the kettle job it takes 17 hours to finish the first time load.
Even for incremental load it takes more than a hour.I tried with increasing commit size and also giving more memory to the job, but still performance is not improving. I think `JSON` input step takes a very long time to parse the data and hence its very slow.
I have these steps in my transformation

1. Mongodb input step
2. Json Input
3. Strings cut
4. If field value is null
5. Concat fields
6. Select values
7. Table output.

Same 4 million records when extracted from postgre was way more fast than mongodb.
Is there a way I can improve the performance?
Please help me.

Thanks,
Deepthi

Comment: You can configure performance monitoring in Kettle and find out exactly which step is taking the longest. You should also be able to get a good idea just by watching the step metrics as it runs. I suspect you're right though, and unfortunately, I have no knowledge of Mongo at all. I would probably do whatever I could to push the extract down into Mongo instead of Kettle.

Comment: Hi Brian , Thanks.. yes by observing the metrics got to know that JSON input takes a very long time as it parses through every row as a string for every transaction. Cannot change my transformation as it is running in production, so if any one knows to improve the performance of JSON step then it would be great because in future we are moving everything to mongo and this can be critical.

Comment: I doubt there's anything you can do directly to the `JSON Input` step. I think you'll have to try to reduce the number of rows you're selecting from the `Mongodb Input Step`, perhaps by changing your query expression. Alternatively, you may be missing indexes in your collections. Not sure what you mean by not being able to change your transform because it's in production. Wouldn't that mean you can't change anything, including your JSON Input step?

Comment: Hi Brian .. what I meant was I have access to change , but wanted to only improve the step performance..You had told like push the extract down into Mongo instead of Kettle so I told kettle job is running in production. however if there is no option to speed up the JSON step then cant do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Run multiple copies of the step.  It sounds like you have mongo input then a json input step to parse the json results right?  So use 4 or 8 copies of the json input step ( or more depending on cpu's) and it'll speed up.

Alternatively do you really need to parse the full json, maybe you can extract the data via a regex or something.

Comment: Hi Thanks I did this .. but still parsing is very slow

Comment: I've heard in several places if you use Javascript functions in the javascript step for parsing the JSON it'll perform significantly better. Jquery functions etc. Have you tried that?